# Converting pounds to euros - Using Parameters

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2013, parameters

I've started a project in C++ to practice the use of parameters and I have encountered a problem in my code and I'm not quite sure why I'm getting the values I'm getting.

Here is my code:
When I run it, the values I receive from the `displayFinalData` output as 0 instead of the values I'm expecting (which should be whatever the conversion is etc).

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    int numInEuros = 0;
    char answer = 'Y';

    double sumEuro = 0;
    double priceEuro = 0;
    int number = 0;

    while ((answer == 'Y') || (answer == 'y'))
    {
        void processAPrice();
        processAPrice();

        void calculateSum(double priceInEuros, double& sumInEuros);
        calculateSum(priceEuro, sumEuro);

        cout << "\nDo you wish to continue? (Y/N): ";
        cin >> answer;

        number += 1;
    }

    void displayFinalData(double sumInEuros, int number);
    displayFinalData(sumEuro, number);

    system("pause");
    return 0;
}

void processAPrice()
{
    double pricePounds;
    double priceEuro;

    void getPriceInPounds(double& priceInPounds);
    getPriceInPounds(pricePounds);

    void convertPriceIntoEuros(double priceInPounds, double& priceInEuros);
    convertPriceIntoEuros(pricePounds, priceEuro);

    void showPriceInEuros(double priceInPounds, double priceInEuros);
    showPriceInEuros(pricePounds, priceEuro);
}

void getPriceInPounds(double& priceInPounds)
{
    cout << ("\nEnter price in pounds: \x9C");
    cin >> priceInPounds;
}

void convertPriceIntoEuros(double priceInPounds, double& priceInEuros)
{
    double conversionRate = 0.82;
    priceInEuros = (priceInPounds / conversionRate);
}

void showPriceInEuros(double priceInPounds, double priceInEuros)
{
    cout << ("\nThe Euro value of \x9C") << priceInPounds << " is EUR " << priceInEuros << "\n";
}

void calculateSum(double priceInEuros, double& sumInEuros)
{
    sumInEuros += priceInEuros;
}

void displayFinalData(double sumInEuro, int number)
{
    cout << "\nThe total sum is: EUR " << sumInEuro << "\n";
    cout << "\nThe average is: EUR " << (sumInEuro / number) << "\n\n";
}
```

Comment: Where did you get the notion to place function declarations within functions?  `void showPriceInEuros(double priceInPounds, double priceInEuros);`  This isn't technically wrong, but technically awkward and is practically never done.  Function declarations usually go outside of all functions (before the function body itself and before any usage of the function).

Comment: Just makes it easier for me to see where all the values are being passed. Goes against any conventions, I know..

Comment: It clutters the code, plus others are reading your post.  Just declare the function outside -- the compiler will let you know if you pass an invalid parameter.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You declared priceEuros variable separately in your processAPrice() function and that gets updated after user inputs price in pounds, but the priceEuro variable in main() is untouched, and keeps incrementing your sumEuro by 0.

If you pass your priceEuros variable in main to the processAPrice() function it would work

```
void processAPrice(double& priceInEuros)
{
    double pricePounds;

    void getPriceInPounds(double& priceInPounds);
    getPriceInPounds(pricePounds);

    void convertPriceIntoEuros(double priceInPounds, double&     priceInEuros);
    convertPriceIntoEuros(pricePounds, priceInEuros);

    void showPriceInEuros(double priceInPounds, double priceInEuros);
    showPriceInEuros(pricePounds, priceInEuros);
}
```

Comment: This would be a better answer if you extracted the function declarations outside of the function (preferable a header file).

Answer (score 0):

I'm *guessing* you want to update the `priceEuros` variable? The problems is that it's a *local* variable. Local variables in different function have no relation, even if the have the same symbolic names.

For variables you want to share between functions you need to make them *global*, i.e. declare them outside the scope of any function.

Comment: That is a solution however, in my task specification it states to only use parameters :\ Your guess it correct though.

Comment: I suggest to prefer to pass variables by reference if they are to be shared and modified, rather than using global variables.

Comment: @b4027184 Then pass the variable from `main` (as a reference) to the functions needing the variable.